# Retemplated ComboBox text not getting trimmed

Tags: wpf

I have a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="IntroOutroList" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCovers}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCoverIndx}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding IntroOutroSelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

and the resources:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="LightGray" />


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="1" Background="#5089ba" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="1"  Margin="1"  Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>



        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton  x:Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />

                            <!--<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Focusable="True" Text="SAVED PRESETS" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"  IsReadOnly="False" BorderThickness="0" />-->
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>

                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Which I hoped would have trimmed the item text that exceeds the text area, but it didn't. Any idea what is missing........................................................?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What *did* it do? Are you still seeing the item texts in the dropdown?

Comment: yes, but they go over the drop-down button

Comment: They go over the drop-down button. On which axis? X, Y, Z, or time? At any rate, I can't reproduce anything you're describing.

Comment: Can you show me two screenshots? The first one: A screenshot of a combobox item going over the drop-down button. The second one: A screenshot of the open dropdown.

Comment: Yes, here they are

Comment: So, you are right....the drop-down is empty

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how you created the "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" thing. That's a new one on me. I'd be interested if you could provide code that replicates that issue.

Comment: If you want the `TextBlock` to display text, bind its `Text` property to the item property you want to display. Is it correct that `AvailableCovers` is a collection of something? What is in the collection? Do the objects in the collection have properties? Pick one. Maybe they have a `Description` property that you want to display. If so, your DataTemplate should contain `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  />`

Comment: Yes, so 'AvailableCovers ' is the observable collection to which the comobox is binded. 'ttttttttttttttttttttttt' is just one of the string elements in this collection

Comment: What's a "string element"?

Comment: It's like if you simply do like this: ObservableCollection<string> AvailableCovers = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"test1", "test2", "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt", "test3"};

Comment: "String". A "string element" is an instance of `System.String`. That was the question. Thank you. Concrete answers are very important. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />`. `Binding Path=.` means "Give me the whole DataContext object, not one of its properties".

Comment: You know what, I bet it's the ComboBox control template that's causing that weird overlap effect. Most likely that's not something you wrote or even are really aware of. Are you using a theme or something?

Comment: Yes, I used some resources. Please see the updated code

Comment: Yeah, the grid in your combobox control template has no columns defined. You put the content presenter on top of the toggle button. And there it is, on top.

Comment: Ok, that should do it. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer successfully resolved your issue, you should click the Accept thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataTemplate needs one change, and you need to make a few changes to your control template as well.

The `DataTemplate` is the easy one. You just need to tell it what text you want to see in the `TextBlock`. Since your items are just strings, you use the whole item instead of one of its properties:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now for the control template.

The `ContentPresenter` is on top of the `ToggleButton` because you put it there. Elements in a grid overlap unless you create rows or columns and assign elements to different rows/columns.

Another issue is that you weren't using your `ItemTemplate` in the `ContentPresenter`, so I bound that property as well. Ideally, you should also handle the case where the `ComboBox` uses `DisplayMemberPath` instead of `ItemTemplate`, but we can let that slide for now. I would have liked to apply `TextBlock.TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` to the `ContentPresenter` rather than in the `ItemTemplate`, but it's not an attached property and you can't do that.

The attributes I added or changed are at the beginning of each element, before `x:Name`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton  
            Grid.Column="1" 
            x:Name="ToggleButton" 
            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
            Focusable="false" 
            IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
            ClickMode="Press"
            />

        <ContentPresenter 
            Grid.Column="0"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            x:Name="ContentSite" 
            IsHitTestVisible="True" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
            TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" 
            />

        <!--<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Focusable="True" Text="SAVED PRESETS" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"  IsReadOnly="False" BorderThickness="0" />-->
        <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
            <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                </ScrollViewer>

            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

## UPDATE

I hadn't even looked at the `ToggleButton` template, but it turns out that the original design made it full width so that the user could click on the text area to open the dropdown. And the `ToggleButton` was providing the background coloration for the whole control. So the above solution should have put the `ToggleButton` behind the `ContentPresenter`, with `Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`.

But that's a funny way of organizing it, and it makes all the borders a bit weird. It's unclear and hard to figure out what to do to change stuff. So I rewrote it.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Border 
            x:Name="Border" 
            Background="#5089ba"
            Width="16"
            />
        <Path 
            x:Name="Arrow" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Fill="White" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
            />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border 
                        x:Name="Border" 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        CornerRadius="1" 
                        Background="#5089ba" 
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        BorderBrush="LightGray"
                        />

                    <!-- Overall border-->
                    <Border 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
                        />

                    <!-- This lets the user click on text area to open the dropdown -->
                    <ToggleButton 
                        x:Name="InvisibleButton"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Opacity="0" 
                        Focusable="False" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        />

                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        x:Name="ContentSite" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="True" 
                        Margin="1,1,0,1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                        TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" 
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" 
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                        />

                    <ToggleButton  
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        Margin="0,1,1,1"
                        x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Focusable="false" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        />

                    <!--<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Focusable="True" Text="SAVED PRESETS" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Visible"  IsReadOnly="False" BorderThickness="0" />-->
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>

                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The only problem is that I actually lose the gray background color of the combobox. If I remove the column definitions, then the background is there, but the text overlaps the button as before. Do you have an idea?

Comment: The quick solution for me is to create a rectangle and fill it gray right beneath the combobox which is now transparent

Comment: @Ivan Just bind the Grid's Background to the styled Background brush: `<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"> ...`. Since you're only replacing the template of the ComboBox, not the whole Style, then it'll get whatever the default Style gave it. When you replace the ControlTemplate, you're replacing *every* visual aspect of the control except (IIRC) Margin. Anything you want to see in there, you've got to do explicitly. That's the great thing about it, but it can make for a lot of work.

Comment: @Ivan Ahhh, now I understand why you put the ContentPresenter after the ToggleButton -- with no columns, the ToggleButton was full width, so it provided the background for the whole ComboBox. So the Borders in the ToggleButton were actually providing the whole background for the entire ComboBox. I never even looked at that ToggleButton template.

Comment: @Ivan OK, I went to figure out exactly what it was all doing, and in the process rewrote both templates, see update.